# How to format numbers with at least one figure after the decimal point

Tags: output-formatting

I'm searching for a way to get `Reals` formatted with at least one figure after the decimal point. So e.g. 3. should be printed as 3.0 and `ScientificForm[300,3]`  as $3.0\times 10^2$. I tried the options `NumberFormat`, `PaddedForm`, `Padding` etc. with no success.

Comment: A related post is: [Rationalizing Numerical Output](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7458600/915703)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here is an idea:

```
SetAttributes[myForm, Listable]
myForm[x_] := 
 If[Abs[Mod[x, 1]] <= $MachineEpsilon, NumberForm[x, {Infinity, 1}], 
  x]
```

Comment: This is a pretty good way for "normal" numbers. But how to to handle `ScientificForm[300.]?

Comment: I am not sure how this would work. `ScientificForm` is a predefined form and perhaps it makes more sense to write your own form and use that in place of of `ScientificForm`.

Answer (score 10):

Maybe you want this :

```
NumberForm[#, {4, 2}] &@{3., 3, 4.}
```

> ```
> {3.00, 3.00, 4.00}
> ```

This should do what you need :

```
number[x_] := If[FractionalPart[x] == 0, NumberForm[x, {Infinity, 1}], x]
```

Let's test this function

```
number /@ {3., 3, -5.53, 4.356, 55}
```

> ```
> {3.0, 3.0, -5.53, 4.356, 55.0}
> ```

Comment: you were a few seconds faster ;-)

Comment: If only a few seconds faster, you were fast too !

Comment: No, that's not exactly what I want. I want to change the output of all numbers which Mma displays ending with a dot to be displayed with one appended 0. So 4.1 is good, but 4. should print 4.0. I don't want to have a fixed number of decimals.

Comment: @PeterBreitfeld I updated my answer to satisfy your needs.

Answer (score 3):

With the help of @ruebenko and @Artes I came to the following solution, writing my own expForm as an alternative to `ScientificForm`:

```
ClearAll[dtZahl]
SetAttributes[dtZahl, Listable]
dtZahl[x_?NumberQ] :=

 If[Abs[Mod[x, 1]] <= $MachineEpsilon, NumberForm[x, {Infinity, 1}], x]
dtZahl[x_] := x

ClearAll[expForm]
expForm[x_?NumberQ] :=
 Module[{me = MantissaExponent[x], num, exp},
  If[MemberQ[{0, 0., 1, 1., -1, -1.}, x], Return[x]];
  exp = Superscript["\[CenterDot]10", me[[2]] - 1];
  num = NumberForm[N[me[[1]]]*10 // dtZahl, 3];
  If[me[[1]] == 0.1, (* no mantissa*)
   num = ""; 
   exp = Superscript[10, me[[2]] - 1],
   If[me[[2]] == 1,  (*range 0..10*)
     exp = ""], (*else*)
   ];
  Row[{num, exp}]
  ]
expForm[x_] := x
```

This looks now as I want:

```
expForm /@ {0, 1, -1, 1.23, 12.3, 123, -123, \[Pi], 0.1, 0.01, 0.0001, 0.123, 0.0123}
```

with the output:

[image]

Comment: I thought you always wanted a decimal point and always wanted at least one digit after the decimal point, even if it's 0. Your `expForm[1]` gives `1` but according to the original question should give `1.0`.

Comment: @murray Yes, but for 0 and 1 I find giving an Integer is fine. In german numbers are never written in the form "27." or ".27" etc, the dot (we use a comma) has alway to be between to digits.